# Apply permutation matrix to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, permutation

I have two identically sized DataFrames (call them `A` and `B`) with the same set of index and column names. `A` and `B` have a different ordering of their (row/column) labels and I want them to be identically labeled so I can directly manipulate the matrices in other programs. Mathematically, there is a permutation matrix `P` that reshuffles one matrix labels to another, so I can apply this transformation by constructing the matrix. I feel however, that this is overkill and a solution should exist within pandas itself.

Is there an easy way to do this pandas without the ugly hack below?

```
# construct A,B ...
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Construct the permutation matrix
permutation = [np.where(B.index==a_idx)[0][0] for a_idx in A.index]
P = np.zeros(A.shape)
for k,row in zip(permutation,P):  row[k] = 1

B2 = (P).dot(B.values).dot(P.T)
B2 = pd.DataFrame(B2, index = A.index, columns = A.index)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`reindex_like`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html) to reorder the rows/columns of one DataFrame to conform to another DataFrame.

```
>>> vals = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=list('def'), index=list('abc'))
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=list('efd'), index=list('bac'))
```

Then to reorder `df1` so that it is the same as `df2`:

```
>>> df1.reindex_like(df2)
   e  f  d
b  4  5  3
a  1  2  0
c  7  8  6
```

Comment: Ah ha! This is exactly what I was looking for, though I think I was using the wrong terminology (permutation, etc...). Hopefully this will help the next like-minded person.